# Как отсортировать значения по столбцу массива, не используя pandas?

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Допустим, есть массив:

```
[[8, 7, 5],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [6, 9, 4]]
```

Какой код надо написать, чтобы на выходе был массив (отсортированный по 1-му столбцу):?

```
[[2, 3, 1],
 [6, 9, 4],
 [8, 7, 5]]
```

Если значения в первом столбце бы совпадали, то их бы надо было отсортировать по второму столбцу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как ни странно:

```
a = [[8, 7, 5], [2, 3, 1], [6, 9, 4], [2,1,5]]
a.sort()
print(a)

>>[[2, 1, 5], [2, 3, 1], [6, 9, 4], [8, 7, 5]]
```

Структурные данные сравниваются по умолчанию по первому элементу, при равенстве  - по второму и т.д.

---

Если второй столбец должен быть ключом:

```
a.sort(key = lambda x:x[1])
>> [[2, 1, 5], [2, 3, 1], [8, 7, 5], [6, 9, 4]]
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать сортировку по второму столбцу?

Comment: Сейчас второй столбец - вторичный ключ (при равенстве первых). Если понадобится использовать второй столбец в качестве первичного ключа - укажите это в параметре key сортировки. Пример  сейчас напишу.

Comment: Есть ещё один вопрос. Допустим, есть два массива: `[8, 2, 6]` и `[3, 5, 7]`. Как сделать так, чтобы после сортировки первого массива второй выглядил так: `[5, 7, 3]` (то есть, 3 остаётся под 8, 5 под 2, 7 под 6)?

Comment: Объедините списки zip, отсортируйте, и расклейте (*). Лучше это отдельным вопросом - кто-то может лучше способ предложить.